# How does a callback in an async code get it's stacktrace?

Tags: javascript, nodes, stack-trace, asynccallback

I've going down the event loop hole and I'm at the point where I want to understand how the stacktrace of a callback is restored.

Let's say we have the following code:

```
async function q() {
  return Promise.resolve(5);
}
async function x () {
  return new Promise(async function exe(resolve) {
    q().then(function xCallback(r) => {
      resolve(r)
    })
  })
};

function y(index) {
  x().then(function yCallback() => {
  console.log('completed async function', {index});
  });
}

y(1)
```

When Promise.resolve(5) is executed it's put inside the Web Apis to be handled by another thread. q() completes, then x completes and then y completes synchronously. The thread that was handling q()'s promise completed and pushed the xCallback into the microtask. When xCallback is being handled through the execution context the callstack in shows xCallback -> exe -> x -> y -> anonymous.

The question is : Is the callstack for a callback stored in the heap and when the callback is pushed into the execution the callstack is restored from heap or something similar?

When Promise.resolve(5) is executed it's put inside the Web Apis to be handled by another thread. q() completes, then x completes and then y completes synchronously. The thread that was handling q()'s promise completed and pushed the xCallback into the microtask. When xCallback is being handled through the execution context the callstack in shows xCallback -> exe -> x -> y -> anonymous.

The question is: Is the callstack for a callback stored in the heap and when the callback is pushed into the execution the callstack is restored from heap or something similar?

Comment: *"When Promise.resolve(5) is executed it's put inside the Web Apis to be handled by another thread."* No. Asynchronous != multi-threaded. Promises are just a means of *observing* the completion of an asynchronous process, and there is only one JavaScript thread involved. (**If** the asynchronous process is being handled by the host environment, it might do the work on another thread, but the promise reactions will run on the same thread your other JavaScript code is running on.)

Comment: A couple of other notes: 1. There's no reason for a function to be marked `async` if it doesn't use `await`. 2. It's best practice **not** to pass an `async` function to something that doesn't do anything with the promise the `async` function will return (for instance, the callback to `new Promise` should not be `async`, because `new Promise` ignores the return value of the callback).

Comment: But re the question: Where and how async stack traces are stored/produced is an implementation detail of the JavaScript engine you're using, and may vary from one engine to another (for instance, V8 might do it one way, SpiderMonkey another way, and JavaScriptCore a different way entirely).

Comment: (Actually, when `Promise.resolve(5)`, specifically, is executed, you **know** there are no other threads involved, because that creates a promise that is already fulfilled. Above I was referring to the more general case of receiving a promise, such as the one from `fetch`. In the general case, if a host-provided function gives you a promise, the host *might* be using a different thread to do the actual work [or may just be using asynchronous I/O or similar].)

Comment: The functions x,y and q are all executed to completion by the main thread and removed from the stack. So I was just wondering how it ever gets back into the stack trace and my initial thought was that the callback context is generally stored in the heap and then just restored when the callback is moved to the execution context. Is that wrong?

Comment: As I said above, where and how async stack traces are stored/produced is an implementation detail of the JavaScript engine you're using, and may vary from one engine to another. If you want to know how a particular engine does it, most of them are open source. Fundamentally, though, it really doesn't matter. Most engines (all major ones) provide async stack traces now (vs. ~5 years ago when they didn't), regardless of precisely how they do it. :-)